# CS50: check50 says Substitution problem output is empty, but it works fine on the terminal

Tags: c, cs50

I tried to do the substitution problem in CS50's Week 2 Problem Set (essentially, we use an encryption key provided by the user to substitute values, preserving the original message case).

When I test the code myself, it prints all the characters correctly, but check50 says there is no output. [See my test results in detail here.](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/16ae4d43c02b5e23b8d2ee7ac96e0088fcae3a2f)

:( encrypts "A" as "Z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
expected "ciphertext: Z...", not ""

My code handles all the edge cases perfectly, but check50 says the substitution gives empty outputs ... but it works fine on my online terminal.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

string substitution(string text, string key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // making sure there's exactly two arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;

        // making sure the key has 26 characters
    } else if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // making sure there is no repeating characters in key
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]); j++)
        {
            if (argv[i] == argv[j] && i != j)
            {
                printf("No repeating characters.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the key is valid...

    printf("plaintext: ");
    string text = get_string("Type a string: ");
    string key = argv[1];
    int l = strlen(text);
    char ciphertext[l + 1];

    // converts the whole key to uppercase
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(key); k++)
    {
        key[k] = toupper(key[k]);
    }

    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // loops through all the characters in text
    int length = strlen(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(text[i]) && toupper(text[i]) == alphabet[j] && isupper(text[i]))
            {
                // printf("%c", key[j]);
                ciphertext[i] = key[j];
                break;
            } else if (isalpha(text[i]) && toupper(text[i]) == alphabet[j] && islower(text[i]))
            {
                ciphertext[i] = tolower(key[j]);
                // printf("%c", tolower(key[j]));
                break;
            } else
            {
                ciphertext[i] = text[i];
                // printf("%c", text[i]);

            }
        }
    }

     // Add null char to make it a string
    ciphertext[l] = '\0';

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    return 0;

}
```

PS: My problem is similar to [this question](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/42600/check50-says-i-have-no-output-on-pset2-substitution-but-my-code-does-output-cor), but there was no solution provided. The code was excluded due to "academic honest policy", but I'm doing this merely because I'm genuinely stuck and I don't want to copy someone's solution.

Edit. 1: I included a piece of the code for brevity, but I was asked for the entire code. I'm working on the improvements you guys suggested.

Comment: How is `l` (small letter L) defined?

Comment: Observation: you shouldn't need the inner loop or the `alphabet` array (where I assume `alphabet[0] = 'A';` .. `alphabet[25] = 'Z';`).   I think you could simplify the logic by using `if (!isalpha(text[i])) { …non-alpha… } else if (isupper(text[i]) { …upper-case… } else { …lower-case… }`.  In the '…lower-case…' section, you'd use `text[i] - 'a' to generate an index 0..25 into the `key` array; in the '…upper-case…' section, you'd subtract `'A'` instead.  This allows you to avoid the inner loop.

Comment: What is the variable `l`? As in: `ciphertext[l] = '\0';` Do you mean: `ciphertext[length] = '\0';`? Please _edit_ your question and post your _entire_ program (with `#include` and all). It should be downloadable and compilable/runnable (assume we have the `cs50` files--which I do). That way we'd know if `l` was a typo posted here or not

Comment: I think your current `else` clause is premature — you need to establish that `text[i]` doesn't match any of the letters before you decide to do that copy.  If you eliminate the inner loop (but not the logic inside it), you should be OK.  That's what my prior comment is suggesting.

Comment: Incidentally, the question on the CS50 site has the code still available, but you have to click on the `edited` link above the moderator's icon to get to https://cs50.stackexchange.com/posts/42600/revisions, which shows the deleted code.  That technique works most places on Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange — AFAIK, it isn't restricted to those with sufficient reputation.

Comment: The linked to code can be improved: no need to use `strlen`. It's _especially_ bad to loop through a string with: `for (i = 0;  i < strlen(text); ++i)` instead of `for (i = 0;  text[i] != 0;  ++i)` This increases linear (O(n)) running time to quadratic (O(n^2)). And "magic numbers": `65 for 'A'` and `97 for 'a'`

Comment: A hint: [As Jonathan said]: You only need to loop through the plain text once (A single non-nested loop). If `chr` were the _current_ char: `if (isupper(chr)) chr = key[chr - 'A'];` Similar for lowercase.

Comment: You can also optimisé first double loop i,j on key with looping j from i+1 and removing test i!=j

Answer (score 0):

by the way you can simply do this to encrypt you don't need all that extra stuff

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
{
    if (islower(plaintext[i]))
    {
        plaintext[i] = tolower(argv[plaintext[i] - 97]);
    }
    else if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
    {
        plaintext[i] = toupper(argv[plaintext[i] - 65]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 97 <-> 'a', 65 <-> 'A'.